# How to ignore first CartesianIndex and get Vector{Int} from findmax?

Tags: julia

The output of `findmax(x, dims=2)` has some strange types. How can I normalize them?

```
julia> x = [10 20; 40 30]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 10  20
 40  30

julia> (maxvalue, maxindex) = findmax(x, dims=2)
([20; 40;;], CartesianIndex{2}[CartesianIndex(1, 2); CartesianIndex(2, 1);;])

julia> maxvalue
2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 20
 40

julia> maxindex
2×1 Matrix{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 2)
 CartesianIndex(2, 1)
```

I want instead:

```
julia> maxvalue
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 20
 40

julia> maxindex
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> findmax.(eachrow(x))
2-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (20, 2)
 (40, 1)
```

alternatively you can index into `CartesianIndex`:

```
julia> getindex.(maxindex, 2)
2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 2
 1
```

Comment: I need to get them into a DataFrame actually, so I want separate vectors. I am going to make a column for the maximum value `df."Maximum" = maxvalue` and a column for the maximum location `df."Max Location" = y[maxindex]`.

Comment: In this case use the second solution or do something along the lines `select(DataFrame(tmp=findmax.(eachrow(x))), :tmp => ["Maximum", "Max Location"])`